# cssの設定を行っているがmarginで間が出来ていない

Tags: html, css

#### 問題

今回の課題として、other-service➡の部分を下のour visionとを余白空けるためにmarginで設定してありますができていません。

#### 目標

前者の画像が現在の画像です。
結果として、後者の画像のようにしたいです。

現在、自分でも問題の追及していますが解決出来ていません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```css
#our-service{
    z-index: 9;
}

.content1{
    margin:  auto;
    padding-top: 125px;
}

.content1-wrp{
    display: flex;
}

h1{
     font-size: 28px;
     font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
     border-top: solid 2px #2da690;
     max-width: 200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-weight: 500px;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding-top: 4px;
     text-align:center;
     white-space: nowrap;
}

.content1-imgs1 img{
 height:665px;
 width: 665px;
 object-fit: contain;
 right: 42vw;
 bottom: -37vw;
}

.servis-text{
    height: 340.5px;
    width: 672px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    right: 13vh;
    bottom: 20vh;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
}

.service-text2{
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    opacity: 0.9;
    height: 373px;
    width: 672px;
    margin-left: 15vh;
    z-index: 2;
}

.service-text3{
    height: 340.5px;
    width: 672px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    right: 13vh;
    bottom: 20vh;
    opacity: 0.9;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans JP', sans-serif;
    z-index: 2;
    bottom: 13vh;
}

.service-text3 img{
    height: 64px;
    width: 76px;
    max-height: 64px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

.img1{
 display: flex;
 height:100px;
 width: 200px;
 object-fit: contain;
 position: relative;
 margin:40px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

.img2{
    display: flex;
    height:100px;
    width: 200px;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: relative;
    margin:40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.img3{
    display: flex;
    height:100px;
    width: 200px;
    object-fit: contain;
    position: relative;
    margin:40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.first-text{
 font-size: 32px;
 margin: -20px 0 20px 45px;
}

.second-text{
    margin:0 0 20px 45px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#content2{
    height: 457px;
    width: 1120px;

}

#content3{
 line-height: 5rem;
    height: 399px;
    width: 100%;
}

.content-imgs2 img{
    height: 457px;
    width: 684px;
  max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
  margin:0 0 0 80vh;
    position: relative;
  bottom:10vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content-imgs3 img{
    height: 399px;
    width: 684px;
    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin:0 0 0 0vh;
    position: relative;
    bottom:10vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

.other-service {
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 2rem;
}

.other-service a {
    color: black;
}

.our-divsion{
    padding: 5rem 0 7rem 0;
    background-image: url(./image/bg01.jpg);
    background-size: 100% auto;
    line-height: 5rem;
}

.vision-service li {
    width: 33.3%;
}

.vision-title h3 {
    font-size: 2.6rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.vision-service {
    display: flex;
}


.vision-text1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  color: #2da690;
  margin: 0 0 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.vision-text2 {
    margin: 0;
font-size: 1rem;
line-height: 1.5rem;
font-weight: 400;
color: #808080;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class=our-service>
  <div class="content1">
    <div class="Our-Service fadeIn_down fadeIn">
      <h1>Our Service</h1>
    </div>
      <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
       <div class="content1-wrp">
        <div class="content1-imgs1">
          <img src="image/educure01.jpg">
        </div>
         <div class="servis-text">
          <img class=img1 src="./image/black.png" alt="">
           <p class=first-text>DXを推進するエンジニア育成</p>
           <p class=second-text>IT事業参入をご検討中の事業者様向けのサービスです。</p>
         </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">
   <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
    <div class="service-text2">
      <img class=img2 src="./image/logo.png" alt="">
      <p class=first-text>未経験から</br>本気でエンジニアへ</p>
      <p class=second-text>「未経験から本気でエンジニア」を目指すプログラミングスクールです。</p>
   　</div>
　  <div class=content-imgs2>
      <img src="./image/techpassion01.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
   </li>
  </div>
  <div id="content3">
   <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
　  <div class=content-imgs3>
      <img src="./image/6c40ac7b707e13491fda6a6b4f02d82d.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="service-text3">
      <img class=img3 src="./image/abb886337b510d088a858a59a12bf114.png" alt="">
      <p class=first-text>人生を変える英会話アプリ</p>
      <p class=second-text>登録者25万人！YouTuber講師ジョージ監修！オンライン英会話アプリ！</p>
   　</div>
   </li>
  <div class="other-service fadeIn_right fadeIn">
  <a href="#">Other-service ➡</a>
</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="our-divsion">
 <li class="fadeIn_down fadeIn">
  <div class="vision-menu">
    <div class="our-vision fadeIn_down fadeIn">
    <h1>our-vision</h1>
    </div>
  </li>
   <div class="vision-title fadeIn_up fadeIn">
    <h3>世界の課題をITで解決して、</br>関わった<strong>世界中の人たちを幸せにする<strong></h3>
   </div>
    <ul class="vision-service">
      <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
        <p class="vision-text1">ITを通じて</br>人々の可能性を広げる</p>
        <p class="vision-text2">イノベーションを起こし新たな価値を創造する</p>
      </li>
      <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
        <p class="vision-text1">世界を代表する</br>自社サービスを作る</br>人々の可能性を広げる</p>
        <p class="vision-text2">世の中にインパクトを与える</p>
      </li>
      <li class="fadeIn_up fadeIn">
        <p class="vision-text1">世界から選ばれる企業へ</p>
        <p class="vision-text2">常に最高のパフォーマンスを発揮します</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class=news>
 <li class="fadeIn_down fadeIn">
   <div class="news-menu">
    <div class="news fadeIn_down fadeIn">
     <h1>News</h1>
  </li>
</div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

見たところ，当該箇所の親である`#content3`が固定の高さ(`height: 399px`を指定されているため，そこからオーバーフロー(はみ出て)してしまっているように見えます．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

CSSのボックスモデルを考える際，仮お気の段階ではあっても構いませんが，こういったブロックごとに高さを決め打ちしてしまうべきではないことが多いです．(特にレスポンシブ対応で顕著になるかもしれません)

なお，marginといえば[margin同士は重なる](https://yan-note.blogspot.com/2014/07/html-cssmargin.html)ので，注意が必要です．(この問題とセットで遭遇するかもしれません)

Comment: 貴重なご意見ありがとうございます。
参考にさせて頂きます。

Comment: 解決しました。
ありがとうございます。